# Fish shell - what's wrong with this syntax?

Tags: fish

I have a bash script which `cat`s a heredoc string, and I'm running it inside a fish shell and then piping it to a `source` call, like so:

~/foo/baz:

```
  1 #!/usr/bin/env bash
  2 
  3 cat << EOS
  4   function bar
  5     echo 'Hello world'
  6   end
  7 EOS
```

From the fish shell:

```
richiethomas@richie ~/foo (master) [126]> ./baz | source
richiethomas@richie ~/foo (master)> bar

Hello world
```

As shown above, this results in the function `bar` being callable when I run `./baz | source`.

However, I get an error when I change the implementation of the `bar` function to the following:

```
  1 #!/usr/bin/env bash
  2 
  3 cat << EOS
  4   function bar 
  5     set myVar 5 
  6     switch $myVar 
  7       case 4 
  8         echo '4' 
  9       case 5 
 10         echo '5' 
 11       case '*' 
 12         echo 'Not found' 
 13     end 
 14   end
 15 EOS
```

When I try to `source` this, I get the following error:

```
richiethomas@richie ~/foo (master) [0|1]> ./baz | source
- (line 1): Missing end to balance this function definition
  function bar
  ^
from sourcing file -
source: Error while reading file '<stdin>'
```

An equivalent function + switch statement works fine when I paste it directly in the fish shell:

```
richiethomas@richie ~/foo (master) [0|1]> function bar
                                              set myVar 5
                                              switch $myVar
                                                  case 4
                                                      echo 'it is 4!'
                                                  case 5
                                                      echo 'it is 5!'
                                                  case '*'
                                                      echo 'not found'
                                              end
                                          end

richiethomas@richie ~/foo (master)> bar

it is 5!
```

I have the same # of `end` statements in both the `baz` file and the code I copy/pasted into the shell, so I suspect the error statement is a red herring?  If so, I don't know what the real error could be.

My goal is to be able to construct a fish function inside the heredoc string of a bash script, then source that bash script from a fish script so that I can call that function.  Where did I go wrong here?

Comment: I don't understand your archtitecture. Are these bash scripts generated dynamically? What aren't these fish functions stored in `~/.config/fish/functions/`?

Comment: These scripts are purely a learning exercise, not part of a permanent set of functions.  So there shouldn't be a need to store them in a permanent config directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Variables (`$myVar`) get expanded in heredocs, unless you quote it:

```bash
cat << 'EOS'
# .....^...^
```

Ref
[3.6.6 Here Documents](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents)